# I need a function in sql server to insert a space in each postion of an input string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, split

I need a function in sql server to insert a space in each position of an input string.
For example, if the input of the function is

```
"example"
```

the output of the function should be

```
word1   word2
e       xample
ex      ample
exa     mple
exam    ple
examp   le
exampl  e
```

Comment: This looks like something better done in application code.

Comment: I would answer the same as Oded. It is possible, I think. But not something I would do with (T-)SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @S varchar(20) = 'example'

select left(@S, number) as word1,
       stuff(@S, 1, number, '') as word2
from master..spt_values
where type = 'P' and
      number between 1 and len(@S)-1
```

Or like this if you want one column with the space inserted:

```
select stuff(@S, number, 0, ' ') as word
from master..spt_values
where type = 'P' and
      number between 2 and len(@S)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString(@Input VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS @tblStringSplitted TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    word1 VARCHAR(100),
    word2 VARCHAR(100)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IX INT
    DECLARE @MAX INT

    SET @IX = 2
    SET @MAX = LEN(@Input)

    WHILE (@IX <= @MAX)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tblStringSplitted(word1, word2)
        VALUES(
            SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, @IX-1),
            SUBSTRING(@Input, @IX, @MAX-@IX+1)
        )       
        SET @IX = @IX + 1
    END

    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Calling it as:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString('example')
```

will return:

```
word1     word2
e         xample
ex        ample
exa       mple
exam      ple
examp     le
exampl    e
```

Answer (score 2):

@Oded is right - this sort of thing is best done in application code as a general rule.

Having said that, its always fun to have a go. The following function will handle what you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @splits table (word1 varchar(MAX), word2 varchar(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

;WITH Numbers ( n ) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + n FROM Numbers WHERE n < LEN(@input)-1 )
INSERT @splits
SELECT
    word1 = SUBSTRING(@input,1,n),
    word2 = SUBSTRING(@input,n+1,LEN(@Input) - n)
FROM Numbers
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )

RETURN

END
```

Called using:

```
select * from dbo.SplitString('example')
```